# Is there a term for words that consist of the same syllable repeated?

Tags: terminology

Words such as "mama", "papa", and "cancan" have only one unique syllable, and the whole word is just that syllable repeated once. Is there a name for such words? I am aware of [reduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication), but I believe it refers only to other forms of a word that consist of repetitions of the base word. I'm looking for a term that refers to the base word consisting of repetitions of a syllable.

Comment: A reduplicative root. In Malay, for instance, where reduplication is often used for something like the plural, there are roots which are nevertheless already reduplicated. So, while _kurakura_ means plural 'turtles', the rhyming verb _purapura_ 'pretend' always appears reduplicated. Oh, and by the way, this probly ought to be moved to linguistics.

Comment: It would appear this question is language-agnostic. It's not specific to English.

Comment: Here's a connected question: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6392/root-reduplication-to-mean-singular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is indeed *reduplication*. That term does not refer just to forms which repeat an existing base word. Reduplication may copy repeat just a syllable, or two syllables, or an entire word, and it frequently happens that only the reduplicated word exists without there being a simpler form.